# Amazon EMR pip install in bootstrap actions runs OK but has no effect

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, amazon-emr

In Amazon EMR, I am using the following script as a custom [bootstrap action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html) to install python packages. The script runs OK (checked the logs, packages installed successfully) but when I open a notebook in Jupyter Lab, I cannot import any of them. If I open a terminal in JupyterLab and run `pip list` or `pip3 list`, none of my packages is there. Even if I go to `/` and run `find . -name mleap` for instance, it does not exist.

Something I have noticed is that on the master node, I am getting all the time an error saying bootstrap action 2 has failed (there is no second action, only one). According to [this](https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-cluster-bootstrap-failed/), it is a rare error which I get in all my clusters. However, my cluster eventually gets created and I can use it.

My script is called `aws-emr-bootstrap-actions.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo python3 -m pip install numpy scikit-learn pandas mleap sagemaker boto3
```

I suspect it might have something to do with a docker image being deployed that invalidates my previous installs or something, but I think (for my Google searches) it is common to use bootstrap actions to install python packages and should work ...

Comment: Are you certain PYSPARK uses Python 3?

Comment: @LukaszTracewski that's a good point but I'm getting the same errors (no module named ...) when I switch to the Python 3 kernel in my notebook.

Comment: Can you check the sys path? That is, find from where the modules are loaded.

Comment: I've found out that the Pyspark kernel uses python 3.7.9 while the Python interpreter that I can open (outside a notebook) from JupyterLab uses python 3.7.8. For some reason today it's working!! and I can see my packages in the Pyspark kernel, but not in the Python 3 kernel. The sys.path is very different in both - I think I read somewhere that Pyspark runs in a docker. Sys.path in Python 3 kernel: '/home/notebook/work',
 '/opt/conda/lib/python37.zip', '/opt/conda/lib/python3.7',  '/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '',  '/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages', ...

Comment: Sys.path for pyspark kernel: '/mnt/tmp', '/mnt/tmp/spark-f8de6a81-563d-4.../userFiles-ac7efb7e-.../py4j-0.10.7-src.zip', '/mnt/tmp/spark-f8de6a81-.../userFiles-ac7efb7e-0d15-4cb7-beed-6e9a7672f058/pyspark.zip', '/mnt/tmp/spark-f8de6a81-563d-4043-908c-30a00902d844/userFiles-ac7efb7e-0d15-4cb7-beed-6e9a7672f058', '/', '/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip', '/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip', '/tmp/1607344911142-0/lib64/python37.zip', '/tmp/1607344911142-0/lib64/python3.7', '/tmp/1607344911142-0/lib64/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7',

Comment: Cool, I am glad we have found the root cause. I will post it as the answer (I realise it does not solve everything, but answers original question on why installation is not working).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PYSPARK`, Python interpreter that Spark is using, is different than the one to which the OP was installing the modules (as confirmed in comments).

Comment: Actually for some reason it seems I was installing the modules right for the Pyspark kernel but cannot be found by the Python 3 kernel, but yeah thanks!